# Reference request: order type of subset of limit ordinals

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, ordinals

Let $\lambda$ be an ordinal, and let $f(\lambda)$ be the ordinal representing the order type of the limit ordinals strictly less than $\lambda$. Then $f$ is a weakly increasing function, $f(\lambda + 2) = f(\lambda+1)$ is always true, and $f(\lambda) \le \lambda$ is obvious.

1. Is there a reference that describes the fixed points of $f$? I would expect at least some infinite cardinal numbers represented as their representative minimal ordinal should be a fixed point; obviously not $\aleph_0$, but I believe any unbounded set of ordinals smaller than $\aleph_1$ must be uncountable.
2. Is there a name/reference for $f$, or perhaps for some canonical one-sided inverse of $f$, or in some other manner a closely related function?

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3106951/isomorphism-from-limit-ordinals-to-ordinals-is-there-a-fixed-point) defines the same function and asks about the same fixed points, but doesn't offer anything in the way of Google-fu assistance.

Comment: Aren't those fixed points just the solutions of the equation $\omega\lambda=\lambda$? So wouldn't they just be $0$ and the ordinals of the form $\omega^\alpha$ where $\alpha\ge\omega$?

Comment: If $$\lambda=\omega^{\omega+\alpha}$$ then $$\lambda=\omega^{1+\omega+\alpha}=\omega\cdot\omega^{\omega+\alpha}=\omega\cdot\lambda$$ is preceded by $\lambda$ limit ordinals.

Comment: Useful search terms: "normal function" and "Veblen function" and "Veblen fixed point" and "principle ordinals" (along with "addition") and "additively decomposable ordinals".

Comment: Maybe the last part of [this 22 September 2006 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/JDKEPe1cSC4/m/k7TFh2R4vSQJ), the section titled "(e) A PARADOX CONCERNING w^w?" Also, search for "additively principal limit ordinals" in [this paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/malq.201900059) (also can be obtained [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/347216669_A_note_on_ordinal_exponentiation_and_derivatives_of_normal_functions)). The 'L' operation/notation in my sci.math post is in [**Linear Orderings**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0125976801) by Rosenstein.